# I think this old, deleted question should be undeleted and historically locked instead

Tags: discussion, support, specific-question, deleted-questions, historical-lock

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1246058/senior-programming-guru-who-cant-program-should-i-find-a-different-career

[image: Senior Programming Guru]

This question has 27,000 views and a score of over 700. Typically, such questions are slam dunks for the historical lock criteria. While it's not a great question, I think there is more useful information in this question than [What's your favorite "programmer" cartoon?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/84556/1768232) and [What is the best comment in source code you have ever encountered?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/184618/1768232).

I'm sure many programmers feel lack of confidence, for SEO in-link reasons I think this question should be undeleted and then immediately historically locked.

Comment: Why? It has been deleted since '11 and *nobody* cared about that in all these 4 years...

Comment: I see no reason to put a historical lock on something like this.  What kind of message would we be sending with a lock on this?

Comment: @Makoto What kind of message do we send when we have a lock on "favorite programmer cartoon"?

Comment: @Braiam Because it got 27000 views in the first two years of SO and could add more traffic to the site

Comment: 27K views is nothing.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker Only 66000 questions in 9.9 million questions have 27000 views, and that includes questions that **haven't been deleted for four years**. This is only 0.6% of all questions on all of SO. It's not nothing.

Comment: @durron597 To warrant undeletion, it is.

Comment: Meh, I'm generally sympathetic to a *lot* of undelete requests, but this? The top voted answer is "become a project manager". The rest is certainly useful, but it's so way, way, off topic...

Comment: @Pekka웃 I agree, that answer is crap and should remain deleted. The accepted answer is not.

Comment: I wonder whether there is some variation of this on http://workplace.stackexchange.com, where it *might* have been a fit (don't quote me on that, though, I don't really know that site)

Comment: @Pekka웃 The Workplace didn't exist until 2012.

Comment: @durron597 That's irrelevant to what Pekka is wondering.

Comment: What I want to know is, why is the "What is the best comment in source code you have ever encountered?" historically locked and not deleted?

Comment: @Little perhaps the two million views have something to do with that.

Comment: @Pekka웃 the [I-suck-at-coding](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/a/2696/168) part of the question is off-topis at TWP. The career switch part of it has been asked and answered over there: [What kind of business fields are available to a programmer who no longer wants to program?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/2658/168)

Comment: @CodeCaster - wow, that *is* a lot of page views

Comment: @gnat yeah, that looks pretty good!

Comment: I would agree that cartoon and best-comment questions are less useful (or rather _more useless_) than this one, but they have 20x and 80x more views, respectively

Comment: @gnat They also haven't been deleted for the last four years.

Comment: I understand that. I merely point that you could look for examples with comparable amount of views, like [20K to 40K](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=locked%3Ayes+is%3Aquestion+views%3A20000..40000)

Comment: @gnat Like [What's the most egregious pop culture perversion of programming?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/175074/1768232)? Which, is, like, duh, obviously, so much more useful than this question.

Comment: yes, like this one. Compared to _that_ garbage, one can really wonder why we didn't keep can't-program question. Though it may end up with pop-culture example being deleted - so you better find more examples like that (if all of them get deleted to prove you wrong, this alone could make your question worth asking:)

Comment: @gnat If all similarly awful questions get deleted as a result of this question, at least it will be consistent. I think inlinking makes all of this worth it, but perhaps not. FWIW our little interchange should probably get promoted to an answer, if you have the time

Comment: (I'll probably post an answer a bit later) wrt inlinking, [that's a pretty good point](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/125172/165773) in my opinion but current "party line" at Stack Exchange seems to be to afford some extent of "making Internet worse" as the price of fixing broken windows. Guess that's why they push so hard for 27K views being not-enough, they assume this indicates that there aren't (many) popular incoming links to that question

Comment: @gnat Well, George is a moderator not an SE employee. I do hope an SE employee eventulaly weighs in on this; it seems to me moderators are incentivized to keeping crap deleted as it makes their job easier (fewer bad examples on the site), so they would have a tendency to think of 27k as not enough... that is just how it seems to me, if that's not the case I apologize in advance.

Comment: from what I've seen so far, in this regard employees position is close to that of moderators; they are certainly well aware of the harm involved in deletion of highly viewed questions but they to nothing to tame it and never ever indicated any substantial interest in this

Comment: Historical locks are _supposed to be_ exceptional; "consistency" is no argument here. Unfortunately, the reasons for the exception are also often opaque: I have no good idea why the "pop culture misrepresentation" question is visible and locked. Still, the mere fact that someone convinced a mod that one particular bit of timewasting GTKY fluff deserved a lock doesn't in itself imply that any other bit deserves it too.

Comment: @durron597 [there you go](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/300727/839601) - reposted my considerations in comments as an answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would agree that *cartoon* and *best-comment* questions are less useful (or rather *more useless*) than one you ask about, but these have 20x and 80x more views, respectively.

You would better look for examples with comparable amount of views, like [20K to 40K](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=locked%3Ayes+is%3Aquestion+views%3A20000..40000) - although, if these examples turn out as blatantly off-topic as that *different career* question, it is more likely that these will be deleted when [exposed at meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269349/839601).

---

In comments, you pointed to incoming links as a reason to keep (and lock) highly viewed inappropriate questions. I think that's generally a [valid concern](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/123386/165773), however some system limitations make it rather slippery to use as an *ultimate* criteria on deciding whether to keep such questions.

Thing is, visual difference between "normal" and historically locked questions is not really as prominent as it may seem to experienced SO users. I recall seeing at meta references to examples when inexperienced users didn't notice the differences and thought that these are normal, legitimate questions, ["Why can't I ask X when Y exists?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/broken-windows)

We are essentially forced to decide whether "harm to the Internet" - link rot caused by deletion of particular question - outweights the harm of it hanging in here and making a broken window for inexperienced users (who sometimes simply can't see / understand what historical lock means). That's why high views count alone doesn't determine whether question gets a historical lock.

Comment: Now *this* does answer my question. +1

Comment: sort of a follow-up, SE team folks don't even bother to make such a simple thing as **[change background color of historically locked posts](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7828/31260)** to help visitors better see the difference between these and normaal SO questions :(

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/98589/200235

Answer (score 6):

Career advice is off-topic for a reason. Not only on SO, but also on the Programmers subsite.

Career advice ("What should I do when I [have|lack] this skillset?") is highly tailored to the asker, rarely really useful and hardly useful for someone else.

About the quality: the highest-upvoted answer is a joke, the rest of it debatable.

So I'd say keep it deleted.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question. Programming cartoons and best comments in source code are also not useful for someone else. Further, if this question wasn't useful for people, it wouldn't have 750 upvotes and 27000 reviews. I think it should be **visible** for **in-link** purposes, but locked with that big banner we all know so well saying "this is not a good, on topic question".

Comment: In other words, you are responding to "should this be undeleted and reopened?" which is not what I'm proposing. I'm proposing: "it should be undeleted and then immediately locked".

Comment: _"I think it should be visible"_ - why? It isn't funny nor useful.

Comment: Because google searches. Because blogs. Because high demand content. Why are funny links worth keeping?

Comment: _"It's being linked to"_ is not a valid reason to keep off-topic content around. _"It's in high demand"_ is not true, it's got a relatively low viewcount as George explained. In order to let it be undeleted, **you** will have to make a pretty decent case as to why it should be, which you haven't. I gave my opinion on why we shouldn't undelete it. If users want to learn about feeling insecure about their capabilities, they should read one of the many blogs about "impostor syndrome", way more useful than this Q&A.